# Taking average of live webcam frames

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I first used this code to capture webcam frames:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    if (!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 15);

    std::vector<cv::Mat> images(100);
    for (framenumb = 0; framenumb < 100; ++framenumb)
    {
        // this is optional, preallocation so there's no allocation
        // during capture
        images[framenumb].create(480, 640, CV_32FC3);
    }
    for (framenumb = 0; framenumb < 100; ++framenumb)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame;
        if (frame.empty()) break; // end of video stream
        imshow("webcam", frame);
        if (waitKey(1) == 27) break; // stop capturing by pressing ESC 
        frame.copyTo(images[framenumb]);
    }
```

and then tried to use the following code to average the captured frames:

```
Mat avgImg;
Mat capturedImg;
for (framenumb = 0; framenumb < 100; ++framenumb)
{
    avgImg.create(480, 640, CV_32FC3);
    capturedImg = images[framenumb];
    cv::accumulate(capturedImg, avgImg);
}
avgImg = avgImg / 100;
avgImg.convertTo(avgImg, CV_8UC3);
imshow("averaged", avgImg);
```

But then it just broke the programme and gave me a black image. Can anyone help me to identify where the error is? Thank you very much

Comment: Try `Mat avgImg(480, 640, CV_32FC3, Scalar());` and then remove the `avgImg.create(...)` line

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

1. Create a zero initialized accumulation image
2. Add every image to it
3. Divide the accumulated image by the number of images

You instead re-create an empty accumulation image at every frame.

The code should be changed as:

```
Mat avgImg(480, 640, CV_32FC3, Scalar()); // Create and zero initialize
Mat capturedImg;
for (framenumb = 0; framenumb < 100; ++framenumb)
{
    // avgImg.create(480, 640, CV_32FC3); // Don't create each time!
    capturedImg = images[framenumb];
    cv::accumulate(capturedImg, avgImg);
}
```

---

You probably can simplify your code as:

```
Mat avgImg(480, 640, CV_32FC3, Scalar()); // Create and zero initialize
for (framenumb = 0; framenumb < 100; ++framenumb)
{
    avgImg += images[framenumb];
}
```